# How does Visual Basic 6 convert integers to booleans?

Tags: vb6, integer, boolean, implicit-conversion, vb6-migration

I am reading the following code in vb6

```
If someInteger Then
    DoSomething
End If
```

I don't know if it means

1. `someInteger == 1`,
2. `someInteger > -1`,
3. `someInteger > 0` or
4. `Convert.ToBoolean(someInteger)`

What's the equivalent expression in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wts33hb3.aspx). It's about VB.NET, but that behavior is unchanged from VB6.

Basically, `If someInteger Then ...` is equivalent to `If someInteger <> 0 Then ...`, so everything that is not zero is `True`, be it, 1, 2, -1, etc.

Comment: One thing that **has** changed in .NET is `Option Strict` that when set on not allow `If someInteger Then` without explicit conversion to a `Boolean`

Answer (score 5):

In VB6 any non-zero value is considered True; zero is false.
I would advice to always specify the expression as it was (and it should be) boolean:

```
If someInteger <> 0 Then ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`If someInteger Then` is true only if `someInteger` is not `0` so;

`if (someInteger != 0) { ...`